# WebRequest StreamFilter as a passthrough filter

Tags: filter, firefox-addon

Is there a way to use [WebRequest StreamFilter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/StreamFilter/ondata) as a pass through filter? I just want to do a `console.log` of all the response body. Is that possible in a non-blocking way?

Using: Mozilla Firefox 64.*+